# Chrome Excel file download error

Tags: php, excel, google-chrome, firefox, phpexcel

I'm generating an excel file from PHP with PHPExcel library and when it's filled with all the data it's is automaticaly downloaded, the problem is that chrome only shows column headers without data, meanwhile firefox downloads de file correctly.

In chrome's console appears this message "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet:"

Anyone may know what can cause this problem? Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution of this issue ? I have the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, i don't really remember, but if i'm not wrong, by restoring presets in chrome the issue dissapeared...

Comment: In case i remember something else I comment it.